# Turn row with 2 different value into 2 column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble tunring a row with only 2 possible value (heads or tails for example ) into 2 column. I found Pivot but it doesn't seems to fit the problem.
Here's a little shema to help you understand what i'm trying to do :

[image]

Into this :

[image]

It's probably not very complicated yet I can't find the good words to explain my problem to google so he give's me the right solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name, date,
       sum(case when type = 'Heads' then result else 0 end) as heads,
       sum(case when type = 'Tails' then result else 0 end) as tails
from t
group by name, date;
```